# Pass selection from Colorbox to parent

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, colorbox

I am using a Colorbox modal for a image selection in one of my forms. Is there a way to dynamically pass the image selection outside of the Colorbox and then close the Colorbox?

I have been searching here on StackOverflow but I cant find anyone else trying to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
After adding Jquery to the file loaded in Colorbox I was able to use
`window.parent.$("#select").after('<input type="hidden" name="image" value="' + img + '">');`